# Lookup an alphanumeric value in a range of a cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, alphanumeric

I'm looking for some help with an excel issue I have.

I have a set of data in alphanumeric ranges that associate to different values. In one column, there are numeric values. In the next column, there are alphanumeric ranges. For example WA001-WA010.

[image: Data Table example here]

What I'm trying to do is return the number associated to the alphanumeric that I'm looking up. However, there are certain alphanumerics in that data range that aren't visible. For example, if I were to look up 'WA020' it should return the value of 2. I was looking into rows and indirect functions for arrays but that doesn't really seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think that there is a formula to do that, you will need to use VBA coding for that.

Comment: Do all ranges start with ```WA```?

Comment: No. There's a lot more data. Some start with WB, WC, WD and so on. But the numerical portions of those alphanumerics are 000-999.

Comment: @amitklein And yea I feel like VBA is needed also...

I think my difficulty lies in trying to figure out how to systematically convert these alphanumeric ranges into an array. I tried doing a =ROW(INDIRECT("START&":"&END)) for WA001 in one column and WA010 in another column, but it only evaluated the numbers.

Comment: You may want to use Power Query to load this data, clean it up and create a proper lookup table where each text value is listed next to the code number. That will require some effort to build, but you can then easily add more ranges to your sheet and just refresh the Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

Such a function now exists. Formulas shown :

[Lookup Formulae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDCkO.png)

And the Results:

[Successful results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRnZj.png)

To solve this problem without editing the contents of the cells, what you're effectively forced to do is build a dataset up using the two vectors (one of indexes and one of values), and then query it for what you want in order to arrive at an index. the dataset in this scenario is a very jagged array of collections of collections of collections, at least, that's how I'd do it. To keep my thoughts straight, I made a quasi-object model for the module:

[Quasi Object Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5aMx.png)

In said photo, Collection Item keys are in braces.

So, if you'd like to implement this function, slap it into a code module in whatever workbook your data exists in.

A quick disclaimer - the following code isn't particularly elegant or efficient, but it does do the task.

```
Option Explicit

' I'm not a fan of 0-based indexing in VBA, so this fixes it for me.
' You could go without, and doing so could be a good academic
' excercise on utilizing VBA for data management.
Private Function ChangeIndex(StrIn() As String) As String()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim temp() As String

    ReDim temp(1 To UBound(StrIn) + 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(StrIn) + 1
        temp(i) = StrIn(i - 1)
    Next i

    ChangeIndex = temp

End Function

'Finds index of first numeric character in string
Private Function FindNumeric(ByVal StrIn As String) As Integer

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(StrIn)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(StrIn, i, 1)) Then
            FindNumeric = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function

'Finds numeric components of textual range
Private Function FindRange(ByVal StrIn As String) As Integer()

    Dim answer(1 To 2) As Integer
    Dim num_pos As Integer
    Dim dash_pos As Integer
    Dim temp As String
    Dim temp_two As String

    dash_pos = InStr(1, StrIn, "-", vbBinaryCompare)
    If dash_pos <> 0 Then
        num_pos = FindNumeric(StrIn)
        temp = Mid(StrIn, num_pos, Len(StrIn) - dash_pos - num_pos + 1)
        answer(1) = CInt(temp)
        temp = Mid(StrIn, dash_pos + 1, Len(StrIn) - dash_pos + 1)
        num_pos = FindNumeric(temp) + dash_pos
        temp = Mid(StrIn, num_pos, Len(StrIn) - dash_pos - (Len(StrIn) - num_pos))
        answer(2) = CInt(temp)
    Else
        num_pos = FindNumeric(StrIn)
        temp = Mid(StrIn, num_pos, Len(StrIn) - dash_pos - num_pos + 1)
        answer(1) = CInt(temp)
        answer(2) = answer(1)
    End If

    FindRange = answer

End Function

Public Function AlphaNumLU(Query As String, IndexVector As range, ValueVector As range) As Variant

    Dim csvs() As String
    Dim entries() As Collection
    Dim alpha As Collection
    Dim numeric As Collection
    Dim temp As String
    Dim q_alpha As String
    Dim q_num As Integer

    Dim entry As Variant
    Dim raw_val As Variant
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim range() As Integer
    Dim alpha_found As Boolean

    'The bare minimum error handling
    If IndexVector.count <> ValueVector.count Then
        MsgBox Prompt:="Input vectors must be of same length"
        AlphaNumLU = "#VALUE"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Import Indexes to collection of entries
    ReDim entries(1 To IndexVector.count)
    For i = 1 To IndexVector.count
        Set entries(i) = New Collection
        temp = IndexVector(i, 1).Value
        entries(i).Add Item:="Entry", Key:="Label"
        entries(i).Add Item:=temp, Key:="Index"
    Next i

    'Import Values as Comma Delineated arrays of string
    For i = 1 To ValueVector.count
        temp = ValueVector(i, 1).Value
        csvs = Split(temp, ",")
        csvs = ChangeIndex(csvs)
        entries(i).Add csvs, "RawVals"
    Next i

    'Construct Textual Components
    For Each entry In entries
        For Each raw_val In entry(3)
            i = FindNumeric(raw_val) - 1
            temp = Mid(raw_val, 1, i)
            If entry.count < 3 Then
                MsgBox "Entry should be composed of items Label, Index, alpha..."
                Exit Function
            ElseIf entry.count = 3 Then
                Set alpha = New Collection
                alpha.Add Item:="text comp", Key:="Label"
                alpha.Add Item:=temp, Key:="Index"
                entry.Add alpha
            Else
                alpha_found = False
                For i = 4 To entry.count
                    If entry(i)(2) = temp Then
                        alpha_found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next i
                If Not alpha_found Then
                    Set alpha = New Collection
                    alpha.Add Item:="text comp", Key:="Label"
                    alpha.Add Item:=temp, Key:="Value"
                    entry.Add alpha
                End If
            End If
        Next raw_val
    Next entry

    'Construct Numerical Components
    For Each entry In entries
        For Each raw_val In entry(3)
            Set numeric = New Collection
            numeric.Add Item:="numeric", Key:="Label"
            range = FindRange(raw_val)
            numeric.Add Item:=range(1), Key:="Min"
            numeric.Add Item:=range(2), Key:="Max"
            temp = Left(raw_val, FindNumeric(raw_val) - 1)
            For i = 4 To entry.count
                If entry(i)(2) = temp Then
                    entry(i).Add numeric
                End If
            Next i
        Next raw_val
    Next entry


    'And Finally, Parse the Massive object we just created for the query.
    q_alpha = Left(Query, FindNumeric(Query) - 1)
    q_num = CInt(Right(Query, Len(Query) - Len(q_alpha)))
    For Each entry In entries
        For i = 4 To entry.count
            If q_alpha = entry(i)(2) Then
                For j = 3 To entry(i).count
                    If q_num >= entry(i)(j)(2) And q_num <= entry(i)(j)(3) Then
                        AlphaNumLU = entry(2)
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    Next entry

    'Give notice if the value doesn't exist
    AlphaNumLU = "Not Found"
 End Function
```

So the moral of the story goes - it might've been wiser to modify the way the data is presented to a lookup function as mentioned by @teylyn. VBA can get it done, but it isn't necessarily pretty.

Comment: You are awesome Jacob! I will give it a shot and let you know how it works out!